# How to send the value of array to previous(one step back) ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: Communicating to parent view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600330/ios-communicating-to-parent-view-controller)

Suppose I have 2 viewControllers named FirstViewController and SecondViewController

Now using navigation I go from FirstViewController to SecondViewController.

Now I have one array named resultArray on SecondViewController

and I want to get the value of resultArray on FirstViewController

then how can I get the value on FirstView Controller?

Any idea?

Comment: To pass data back from child to parent view controller you need to use **Protocols and Delegates**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600330/ios-communicating-to-parent-view-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in following way:

in "FirstViewController" file:

1) Create array object for example: arrTest;

2) Create one method for example:

```
-(void)getArrayValue:(NSMutableArray *)pArr
{
     arrTest = pArr;
}
```

3) call method of "SecondViewController" before pushing it:

```
[objSecondViewController setParent:self];\
```

Now, in "SecondViewController" file:

.h file:

```
@class FirstViewController;
```

in .m file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
```

And

1) Declare one variable in .h file:

```
id parent;
```

2) Declare and create one method ".h" and ".m" file:

```
-(void)setParent:(id)pID
{
    parent=pID;
}
```

3) When you come up with array then call method like:

```
[parent getArrayValue: <your_new_array>];
```

Hope, you got an idea of what you want.

Happy Coding!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The answer form @Nishant B (and the other subsequent answers) will work.

Since you're using a UINavigationController, and you want to access the controller one step back, you can also do this within your SecondViewController:

```
NSUInteger count = [[self navigationController].childViewControllers count];
FirstViewController* firstVC = [[self.navigationController childViewControllers] 
    objectAtIndex:count -2];
[firstVC setSomeValue:someValue];
```

Comment: NSUInteger count = [[self navigationController].childViewControllers count];
    DatesTableViewController *datesTable = [[self.navigationController childViewControllers]
                                    objectAtIndex:count -2];
    [datesTable setTempArray:resultArray];
    
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I have done like this but my tempArray gives me null value

Comment: There's another problem too, then. Try ome log statements or stepping through with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is create a Constructor in your first class for e.g.

```
-(void)initWithArrayOfSecondClass:(NSMutableArray *)arr_OfSecondClass;
{
    arr_FirstClassArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arr_OfSecondClass];

}
```

From your second class send this array as :

```
[objOfFirstClass initWithArrayOfSecondClass:resultArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a method of using local notifications.

Say you want to send data from B to A.

Do the following in B when you press a button or so:

```
- (NSString *) saveAndExit
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"AnswerValue" object: answerView.text];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return @"abc";
}
```

And in A's `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"AnswerValue" object:nil];
```

Also add the following method:

```
- (void) incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
NSString *result = [notification object];
```

}

The notification name has to be the same for both. In this case, the name is AnswerValue. This will send the value "abc" from B to A and gets stored in `result`.